# How can I round up the number of periodic digits?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal, precision

I have two numbers, one I get by calculating it and the other one I bring it from the database.

```
calculated = 2.183333333333333
database   = 2.18333333333333
```

But when I compare them to know if they are the same, I return `False` when it should be `True`.

There is some way to limit the number of periodic numbers, but not to affect decimals that are not periodic, for example:

```
2.1748888888888 -> 2.1748
1.23333333      -> 1.23
```

Comment: To factor in minor differences: `abs(calculated - database) < epsilon`, pick an epsilon that works for you.  A slightly more flexible version of this is built into the `math` module.

Comment: 2.1748888888888 -> 2.1748 is just wrong. It should be  2.17489 or 2.1749 unless you don't plan on using it for any calculations.

Comment: I just want to validate if they are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) method:

```
>>> from math import isclose
>>> calculated = 2.183333333333333
>>> database   = 2.18333333333333
>>> isclose(calculated, database)
True
```

This allows for setting the relative tolerance and minimum absolute tolerance as well refer to the docs for more explanation.